# Dataplex API Tag Policies

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-data-catalog, google-dataplex

I'm on exploration Dataplex API with Python in Google Documentation, there is documentation to Get Lake, Zone, Assets, etc. I've explored that documentation, but I didn't find any documentation related to Tag Policies, for example, I need to attach my Tag Template and add Policy Tag to my BigQuery Table via API.

Is it possible to attach Tag Template and add Policy Tag into BigQuery Table via API?

Here is the link that I've explored:

[Dataplex API Service](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/dataplex/latest/google.cloud.dataplex_v1.services.dataplex_service.DataplexServiceClient)

[Dataplex API Metadata Service](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/dataplex/latest/google.cloud.dataplex_v1.services.metadata_service.MetadataServiceClient#google_cloud_dataplex_v1_services_metadata_service_MetadataServiceClient_list_entities)

[Data Catalog API](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/datacatalog/latest/google.cloud.datacatalog_v1.services.policy_tag_manager.PolicyTagManagerClient#google_cloud_datacatalog_v1_services_policy_tag_manager_PolicyTagManagerClient_update_policy_tag)

Answer (score 0):

for attaching tag templates to BigQuery table, first you will have to lookup the entry in dataplex using api

https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/datacatalog/latest/google.cloud.datacatalog_v1.types.LookupEntryRequest

and then attach is to table using api

https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/datacatalog/latest/google.cloud.datacatalog_v1.types.CreateTagRequest

here's sample code, this creates tag template and also attaches it to table in same code base

https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/samples/data-catalog-quickstart

and to attach policy, use this api

https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/datacatalog/latest/google.cloud.datacatalog_v1.types.CreatePolicyTagRequest

hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, what basically does this Entry do? Why do I need to create the entry first?

Comment: Hi there, basically entry is to search the object first in data catalog and then enables attaching by calling the createTagRequest method. I will respond as new answer in detail about my steps.

Comment: hi @MADFROST , did my answer below helped? if yes can you pls mark it as answered? thank you

Answer (score 0):

again.

To simulate the pythonic api's behaviour, I used google cloud api explorer to explain in detail. see below.

The entry lookup is to search for object(s) you want to attach a tag/tag templates

Basically here's how I simulated the api calls using api explorer

1. To attach a tag to a BigQuery table, first step is to search the table up using Datacatalog api url below

[LookupEntryRequest](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rest/v1/entries/lookup)

The parameters I passed to get below response is
sqlResource: "bigquery.table.myproject.zz_DataSet.tblOne"

Above should give you output as

```
{
  "name": "projects/myproject/locations/australia-southeast2/entryGroups/@bigquery/entries/mykey",
  "type": "TABLE",
  "schema": {
    "columns": [
      {
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "column": "firstname"
      },
      {
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "column": "lastname"
      }
    ]
  },
  "sourceSystemTimestamps": {
    "createTime": "2023-01-16T04:22:49.397Z",
    "updateTime": "2023-01-16T04:22:49.397Z"
  },
  "linkedResource": "//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/myproject/datasets/zz_DataSet/tables/tblOne",
  "bigqueryTableSpec": {
    "tableSourceType": "BIGQUERY_TABLE"
  },
  "usageSignal": {
    "updateTime": "2023-02-05T07:59:59.928Z",
    "usageWithinTimeRange": {
      "30D": {
        "totalCompletions": 7,
        "totalFailures": 1,
        "totalExecutionTimeForCompletionsMillis": 7385
      }
    }
  },
  "integratedSystem": "BIGQUERY",
  "fullyQualifiedName": "bigquery:myproject.zz_DataSet.tblOne"
}
```

The search gives you ability to query multiple tables or attach tags at Dataset level too, see parameters section on link above.

This is why I suggest you use entry look up first as its more scalable code.

2. API Call two: This is how i simulated the attach tag to resource. If you go to link below

[CreateTagRequest](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.entryGroups.entries.tags/create)

As an example: I pre created an tag template from console and then used the template-id value to pass as a parameter to the request

**Input:**

`parent: projects/myproject/locations/australia-southeast2/entryGroups/@bigquery/entries/mykey` from above name element
request body:

```
{
  "template": "projects/myproject/locations/australia-southeast1/tagTemplates/api_call_test_tag_template",
  "fields": {
    "name": {
      "stringValue": "apitestcall"
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**
Below is the response generated and if you see in data catalog console, you will see bigquery table with the tag template attached to it with value to name field as "apitestcall" attached to it. see image attached [image: here]

```
{
  "name": "projects/myproject/locations/australia-southeast2/entryGroups/@bigquery/entries/mykey/tags/tagsKey",
  "template": "projects/myproject/locations/australia-southeast1/tagTemplates/api_call_test_tag_template",
  "fields": {
    "name": {
      "displayName": "name",
      "stringValue": "apitestcall"
    }
  },
  "templateDisplayName": "api-call-test-tag-template"
}
```

Finally, please do make sure you have all the correct IAM permissions required for this task.